# float type column in pandas to convert to tuple/list

Tags: pandas

I have pandas object and column type is float

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.12 , 37.95])
```

but when I change column to tuple/list, the number has more digit behint decimal point , how can I fix it?

```
print(tuple(df[0]))
(1.1200000000000001, 37.950000000000003)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me works first convert to `list` and then to `tuple`:

```
print(df[0].tolist())
[1.12, 37.95]

print(tuple(df[0].tolist()))
(1.12, 37.95)
```

Comment: Thanks , I'll try it